# Julia string interpolation followed by exclamation mark

Tags: julia

I would like to do something like this:

```
function say(name, age)
    println("$name is $age!")
end
```

But this gives me an error because Julia thinks age! is the name of the variable. If I add a space between $age and ! then the printed string has a space between age and !, which I don't want. I tried \! which I saw elsewhere but my current Julia version gives me invalid escape sequence error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add brackets

```
println("$name is $(age)!")
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is great, but just in case you want other ways to do it, here are two more ways (though not using string interpolation as in your question):

```
function say1(name, age)
    println(name, " is ", age, "!")
end

function say2(name, age)
    println(string(name, " is ", age, "!"))
end

say1("Tom", 32)
## Tom is 32!

say2("Tom", 32)
## Tom is 32!
```